# [Android]How to put ongoing call on HOLD using ADB commands

Tags: android, automation, command, adb, call

I tried below commands for making outgoing call using ADB command and it's working

```
adb -s XYZWER56RITYDFS shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:555-5555
```

But not able to put call on HOLD I tried below command but its not working

```
adb -s XYZWER56RITYDFS shell am start -a android.intent.action.ON_HOLD
```

How can I achieve this using any **adb keyevent or adb command to put ongoing call on hold**.